# Why does none type give int error? When deleted says indicies must be int and not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, nonetype

I'm making a text adventure game based on rooms. If you run the code, it works if you go within the room boundaries (i.e start at bedroom 2 and go to bedroom 1 vice versa), however as soon as you go out of the boundaries, it gives an error:

```
>>> print(room_list[int(current_room)][0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Upon deleting the `int()`, I get a different error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How do I fix it to retain the `None` type? Or just make the code work. Below is my code.

```
def main():
    done = False
    room_list = []
    current_room = 0

    # Append rooms to different numbers
    room = ["\nYou are in bedroom 2.\nThere is a passage north and east.", "3", "1", None, None]  # Room name, N, E S, W
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in at southern hall.\nThere is a passage  north and east.", "4", "2", None, "0"]
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in the dining room.\nThere is a passage north and west.", "5", None, None, "1"]
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in bedroom 1.\nThere is a passage east and south.", None, "4", "0", None]
    room_list.append(room)

    while not done:
        print(room_list[int(current_room)][0])
        answer = input('What direction? ')

        # Check for correct direction and check if exists
        if answer == "n":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][1]
            current_room = next_room
            if next_room == None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")

        elif answer == "e":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][2]
            current_room = next_room
            if next_room == None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")

        elif answer == "s":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][3]
            current_room = next_room
            if next_room == None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")

        elif answer == "w":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][4]
            current_room = next_room
            if next_room == None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")

        elif answer == "q":
            done = True

        else:
            print("Invalid destination, try again.")

main()
```

Comment: Well, because `current_room` (or `next_room`) is `None`... You should move `current_room = next_room` after the `if` statement, under an `else` clause

Answer (score 0):

Well, because `current_room` (or `next_room`) is `None`... You should move `current_room = next_room` after the `if` statement, under an `else` clause

```
def main():
    done = False
    room_list = []
    current_room = 0

    # Append rooms to different numbers
    room = ["\nYou are in bedroom 2.\nThere is a passage north and east.", "3", "1", None, None]  # Room name, N, E S, W
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in at southern hall.\nThere is a passage  north and east.", "4", "2", None, "0"]
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in the dining room.\nThere is a passage north and west.", "5", None, None, "1"]
    room_list.append(room)

    room = ["\nYou are in bedroom 1.\nThere is a passage east and south.", None, "4", "0", None]
    room_list.append(room)

    while not done:
        print(room_list[int(current_room)][0])
        answer = input('What direction? ')

        # Check for correct direction and check if exists
        if answer == "n":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][1]
            if next_room is None: # == None can be replaced with is None
                print("You can't go that way. ")
            else:
                current_room = next_room

        elif answer == "e":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][2]
            if next_room is None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")
            else:
                current_room = next_room

        elif answer == "s":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][3]
            if next_room is None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")
            else:
                current_room = next_room

        elif answer == "w":
            next_room = room_list[int(current_room)][4]
            if next_room is None:
                print("You can't go that way. ")
            else:
                current_room = next_room

        elif answer == "q":
            done = True

        else:
            print("Invalid destination, try again.")

main()
```